# Is it possible to trigger an webhook without updating a git repo?

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I realize you would normally need to push to or merge a branch to trigger a webhook, but I was wondering if it is possible to generate one with Jenkins, or natively with git (for example via a REST call) which generates a webhook without any changes to the repo in any way whatsoever?

Comment: Yes, It is possible, it just an HTTP request. But, if the goal is to trigger a Jenkins job execution manually, it may be easier justo to Execute it from Jenkins UI.

Comment: Do you want to trigger the Jenkins job or trigger the webhook (which sits wherever you repo is) which triggers the job?

Comment: I am using Jenkins for build and testing steps for an image. Once those steps have completed, another set of processes take place outside of Jenkins. For these processes to be triggered, I need to trigger a webhook in a git repo, but nothing in the git repo will be changed. I would like Jenkins to perform this action (trigger the webhook). So the HTTP request  @Gonzalo Matheu mentions sounds promising, although I still don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Look at using [HTTP Request plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request) then. If that works for you, clarify details in the question and I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> but I was wondering if it is possible to generate one with Jenkins, or natively with git

If you mean that you wish to trigger Jenkins job without any git commit you can simply call it with a REST API.

Login to Jenkins - copy the `build` link and use it via curl or any other programming way of your choice.

Since GitHub webhooks invoke your given url you can test it yourself.

[image]

Comment: Hello, this won't work for my use case. I don't need to trigger a Jenkins job. The Jenkins build is already running. I am using Jenkins for build and testing steps for an image. Once those steps have completed, another set of processes take place outside of Jenkins. For these processes to be triggered, I need to trigger a webhook in a git repo, but nothing in the git repo will be changed. I would like Jenkins to perform this action (trigger the webhook).